# How to programmatically check if microphone and speaker are used by other application or not

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, core-audio

I want to check if microphone and speaker is being used by other applications or not on iPhone. Is it possible to do that?

I used the below code.

```
  UInt32 otherAudioIsPlaying;                                   
  UInt32 propertySize = sizeof (otherAudioIsPlaying);
  OSStatus result = AudioSessionGetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying,
                                                 &propertySize,&otherAudioIsPlaying);
```

However, when I just open VoiceMemos, not press the start button yet, the result is that otherAudioIsPlaying is 1.

Comment: What is the value of `result` after the call?  i.e. Is the call to `AudioSessionGetProperty` failing?

Comment: @highlycaffeinated, I mean that after the line to get the property, I get the value of the variable otherAudioIsPlaying as 1 even VoiceMemo is not recording.